# Error calling Python module function in MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, migration, workbench

I'm kind of at my wits end here, and so far have had no feedback from the MySQL Workbench bug reporting site, so I thought I'd throw this question/problem out to more sites.

I'm attempting to migrate from a MSSQL server on a Windows Server 2003 machine to MySQL server running on a Centos 6.5 VM. I can connect to the source and target databases, select a schemata, and runs through a pass through once for retrieving tables.  After this the process fails and throws the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mssql_grt.py", line 409, in reverseEngineer
    reverseEngineerProcedures(connection, schema)
  File "/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/db_mssql_grt.py", line 1016, in reverseEngineerProcedures
    for idx, (proc_count, proc_name, proc_definition) in enumerate(cursor):
MemoryError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries/workbench/wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_schema_selection.py", line 160, in task_reveng
    self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()
  File "/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules/migration.py", line 353, in reverseEngineer
    self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection, self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames, self.state.applicationData)
SystemError: MemoryError(""): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.reverseEngineer
ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemata: MemoryError(""): error calling Python module function DbMssqlRE.reverseEngineer
Failed
```

I thought this was initally a memory error, so I've upped the memory on the box to 16 GiB.  This error also occurs on any size DBs, as I've tried very minimal sized ones with hardly any tables.

Any thoughts?  Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into this.  I had the same problem and fixed it by getting rid of non-ASCII characters in schemas, tables....basically all MSSQL objects.  This was confounded by the fact that I had SQL# (www.sqlsharp.com) installed, which adds a number of functions and stored procs with a schema called SQL#.  You can remove that with this command:

```
EXEC SQL#.SQLsharp_Uninstall
```

Once you get rid of non-ASCII chars, the migration works.

Comment: Ok but how to fix it if you actually need non-ASCII characters in the script?

Answer (score 0):

The OP (I assume) closed their [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71833) with this message:

> [...] I figured out a work around, or the flaw in the system perhaps.  Turns out that Null values were not allowed inside the Datetime fields when doing a migration.  I turned every Datetime field in my database to a default value and migrated it successfully after that.